# Subquery is not returning a count value from a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

Hello I am new to postgresql and have been stuck on the following problem for awhile. Below I have two tables:
Table 1:
**avatar**

```
  login   |    name     | gender |    race    
----------+-------------+--------+------------
 agnetha  | Flutter Shy | F      | faerie
 agnetha  | Flit        | F      | faerie
 agnetha  | Whisp       | F      | faerie
 astral   | Lightning   | F      | raccoon
 astral   | Elphaba     | F      | wizard
 bobby    | Steve       | M      | wizard
 bobby    | Wayne       | M      | footballer
 bobby    | Smiley      | M      | shark
 ....
```

Table 2: **player**

```
  login   |  name   | gender |     address     |       joined        
----------+---------+--------+-----------------+---------------------
 agnetha  | Sarah   | F      | 191 Howth Ave   | 2016-08-01 17:50:44
 astral   | Jessie  | F      | 81 Franklin St  | 2016-05-28 21:21:21
 bobby    | Robert  | M      | 7 Avenue Rd     | 2016-07-19 12:00:59
 cait     | Caitlin | F      | 444 Sycamore Dr | 2016-08-05 23:51:17
 carter   | Lucy    | F      | 213 John Ave    | 2016-07-08 19:28:46
 cash     | Thomas  | M      | 213 John Ave    | 2016-07-04 15:37:59
....
```

My task is to use both tables and find out which logins changed their gender in the avatar table and display the sum of "avatars" an individual has. Example agnetha has 3 avatars, astral has 2, bobby has 3.

**My issue is that when I try to count using a subquery, postgresql says that** *more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*

This is what I've written as my query so far

```
SELECT player.login,player.name,player.gender, 
(SELECT count(avatar.login) FROM avatar group by login order by login)as avatars 
FROM player INNER JOIN avatar ON player.login = avatar.login AND avatar.gender <> player.gender 
GROUP BY avatar.login, player.login ORDER by login;
```

Any idea how I can get the count of all the avatars per login and display them on a table that looks like this:

```
  login  |  name   | gender | avatars 
---------+---------+--------+---------
 carter  | Lucy    | F      |       3
 coder   | Jeff    | M      |       3
 dazzle  | Alice   | F      |       3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm . . . I think you want aggregation with filtering:

```
select p.login, p.name, p.gender, count(*)
from player p join
     avatar a
     on p.login = a.login
group by p.login, p.name, p.gender
having count(*) filter (where a.gender <> p.gender) > 0;
```

The `count(*)` counts all the avatars.  The `having` clause checks counts the number the genders that are different, requiring that the `logins` have at least one mismatch.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I was really overcomplicating it...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the group by, add where condition and adjust the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.login), p.name, p.gender, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM avatar WHERE avatar.login = p.login) AS avatars 
FROM player p INNER JOIN avatar a ON p.login = a.login AND a.gender <> 
p.gender 
ORDER BY p.login;
```